# Link error using old libraries

Tags: linker, xcode7, static-libraries

I am trying to use third-party libraries (.a) , for which I dont have the source code, that worked in an older app. I imported the older app into Xcode 7 and built and ran it successfully. The libraries were dependent on system libraries which had extension .dylib The program still worked.

I then tried to build a new app using the same libraries. However, I had to replace the system libraries with their .tbd equivalents. When I issued the build command, I got link errors such as shown below where the library name is libavutil.a

```
ld: library not found for -lavutil
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation
```

I read in stack overflow posts about the need to add to the 'other linker flags' in the build settings.

My questions are:

1. Do I need to add flags (to Debug and Release) such as lavutil for libavutil.a or flags for the system libraries -lc++ for libc++?
2. Am I on the right track? Or is there some other solution to the
   linker errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading through some SO posts on similar linker errors encountered by others, it was suggested that instead of adding a `-lavutil` like statement to the `other linker flags`, I could drag and drop the libraries into the window that opens up for multiple values. This worked well. Drag and drop maintains the right relative directory structure and removes the ambiguity that the linker may encounter to find the libraries. The linker errors were eliminated and I could execute the program.

In summary, I switched to Xcode 7, changed target to 9.2, dragged my third-party libraries, and built and ran.